# Android: MenuDrawer/SlidingMenu/SlidingDrawer as system overlay

Tags: android, slidingdrawer, slidingmenu

For my application, I want to add a certain type of drawer as a system overlay. The handle for the drawer has to be small, while the menu itself should be able to cover the whole screen. 
Could anyone help please?

Problems with each type of drawer:
MenuDrawer:

- Size of menu and content are always the same. I want a small content with a big menu that slides open.

SlidingMenu:

- Same as MenuDrawer, but I also didn't get the drawer on the top side to work.

SlidingDrawer:

- The content showed and the handle didn't.

Any help is appreciated.
I've looked at the answers here at XDA but none of them could help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the size of the SlidingMenu to whatever you want using the following syntax:

```
menu.setBehindWidthRes("300dp");
```

Comment: And what about the size of the view on the foreground (the "content")? Doesn't it resize with that?